# Why does Kotlin not automatically cast KFunction1 to Matcher in Hamkrest?

Tags: kotlin, hamcrest

Looking at Hamkrest's github, the [matcher tests](https://github.com/npryce/hamkrest/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/com/natpryce/hamkrest/matching_tests.kt) include this:

```
fun isRipe(f: Fruit): Boolean = f.ripeness >= 0.5
fun isCookingApple(a: Apple): Boolean = a.forCooking

...

val mA: Matcher<Apple> = ::isRipe and ::isCookingApple
```

However, when I replicate this code I get a compiler error:

> Error:(42, 45) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is
>   `KFunction1<@ParameterName Fruit, Boolean>` but `Matcher<Fruit>` was
>   expected

Why?

Comment: for me it works... did you maybe import the wrong `and` extension or something?